# Select in Excel a cell for which the row index is in A1 and the column index is in A2

Tags: microsoft-excel

My question is for most of you guys simple. I want to select a cell for which the row index is in A1 and the column index is in A2. The variable Name_it will then    have the name contained in cell (A1,A2)

Comment: Is this in VBA or in a formula?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the INDIRECT function.

```
=INDIRECT(ref_text_, [a1])
```

This function will allow you to feed a string as an input and it will retrieve the cell based on that input.  In your case you would simply put:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & A2)
```

where the & will concatenate the cell you are referencing

**If you are using a number as your column input**

If you use a number for "col" instead of the letters that Excel uses, you can also use the address function:

```
=ADDRESS(row_num, col_num)
```

Given a row number and column number, this function will return the corresponding cell in the format "$A$1". This can of course be coupled with the INDIRECT function above to make something like this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1,A2))
```

where A1 represents the column index and A2 the row index

Comment: The second part of the answer will work, but not the first, at least as written.  The question says the row index is in A1 and the column index is in A2.  You could use INDIRECT with the R1C1 option and the inclusion of the "r" and "c" text, but INDIRECT(A1&A2) won't work.

Comment: @fixer1234 If A2 is a letter then it works

Comment: Rows don't have letters.  The question says that A1 is the row index.  Also, the second parameter would need to be the row for that to work and the question says A2 is the column index.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

INDIRECT will work for this with the R1C1 addressing option.  Assuming A1 contains the row number and A2 contains the column number:

```
=INDIRECT("r" & A1 & "C" & A2,0)
```

You need to create a text string the evaluates to RxCy, where `x` and `y` are the row and column numbers.  You also need to use `0` or `false` as the last parameter to indicate the R1C1 address style.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the Followings:**

1. Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor and from 
   Menu click **View command** then **Immediate 
   Window.**
2. Write this code and finish with `Enter`.

   ```
   Cells(2, 1).Select
   ```

Baisc command Syntax is,

```
Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex).Select
```

**Note,** it will place cursor to Cell `A2`.